# oauth2client.clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError: ('Error opening file',client_serect.json', 'No such file or directory', 2)

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I try to get access to my client_serect.py + gmail_read.py & client_serect.json are in the same directory but I always get to error above:

gmail_read.py

```
# Creating a storage.JSON file with authentication details
    SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify' # we are using modify and not readonly, as we will be marking the messages Read
    store = file.Storage('storage.json') 
    #CLIENT_SERECT_FILE = './client_serect.json'
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('D:/GitHub/SourceDKPCTuxa/server/client_serect.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    GMAIL = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

client_serect.json Note (...) i reduce for security

```
{"installed":{"client_id":"967939116536-0ljgbv24eo52d1oi5u5nervg2 (...),"redirect_uris":["http://localhost"]}}
```

[image]

If it success, I can get the authorization of accessing my gmail account
[image]

Comment: also I have already tried change / to \, and give the lesser path like 

flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('D:/GitHub/SourceDKPCTuxa/server/client_serect.json', SCOPES)

to

flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_serect.json', SCOPES)

But the result is still the same

Comment: are you sure the file isnt .json.json ?

Answer (score 1):

The file you are trying to open is called client_secret.json. You are trying to access it by the name client_serect.json, please double check spelling before posting on stack overflow.